# Spring securtity 5 - intercept-url requires-channel in java configuration

Tags: java, spring-security, https

I'm migrate xml Spring security configuration to Java configuration based on WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. In xml configuration I can specify requires-channel per intercept-url ex.:

```
<sec:http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
          use-expressions="true"
          disable-url-rewriting="false">

    <!-- ERRORS -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/error/**" requires-channel="any"/>

    <!-- private -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/`private/**" requires-channel="https"/>
</sec:http>
```

In my java configuration I've something like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requiresChannel()          /** How can specify channels at authorizeRequest level?  **/
            .channelProcessors(channelProcessors()).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/error/**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/private/**")
            .authenticated();
}
```

How can specify channels at authorizeRequest level?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify patterns in Java configuration as well. The `requiresChannel` block is unrelated to what you specify in `authorizeRequests`.

Here is the equivalent configuration

```
http
    .requiresChannel(channel -> channel
        .antMatchers("/error/**").requires(ChannelDecisionManagerImpl.ANY_CHANNEL)
        .antMatchers("/private/**").requiresSecure()
    );
```